# How to configure parameter reexec of debug_traceTransaction?

Tags: contract-debugging

I am trying to use `debug_traceTransaction` to scan the internal transactions of smart contracts, so I need set the value of **reexec**, what value should I use? It seems that **reexec** is the number of blocks the EVM need to re-execute to generate the desired state.

```
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      method: "debug_traceTransaction",
      params: [txHash, {tracer: "callTracer", reexec: **??** }],
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: "2"
    }
```